# Inheriting a struct privately

Tags: c++, class, oop, design-patterns, g++

Suppose we have this:

```
class Father
{
struct features
    {
        string hairColor = blonde;
        int age = 1;
        bool dumb = true;
    } m_Features; 

public:
    Father();
    ~Father();

    bool isDumb() { return m_Features.dumb; }
};
```

Then we have another class:

```
class FatherHandler : private Father
{
public:
    // constructors here

    void handle(Father *fa);
};
```

And now in the implementation:

```
void FatherHandler::handle(Father *fa)
{
    if (fa->isDumb)
    {
        m_Features.dumb = true; 
    }
}
```

The g++ compiler does not allow the above code because m_Features is private; however I'm inheriting from Father privately; therefore it should be allowed. How can the above code be modified such that FatherHandler can modify Father without triggering this compile-time error? Note that I inherit privately to denote the 'uses' criteria, rather than inheriting publicly which uses the 'is-a' criteria.

Comment: First, why is `m_Features` private and not protected? Second, why not use encapsulation vs. inheritance? You admit yourself that this is not a "is-a" situation.

Comment: You should really try to post an MCVE. Most of the code in your sample distracts from the issue.

Comment: I'm only experimenting here. I did overlook that private inheritance isn't what it's described as.

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting privately means the public and protected members of the base class(es) are made private in the inheriting class. The derived class still cannot access the private members unless it is specified as a friend.